# Open file in different directory

Tags: python, directory

I've written a function and I want to open a file in a subdirectory 'data'.

```
def _save_exrates(date, rates):
    """
    Saves the exchange rates data for date 'date' in the appropriate exchange 
    rates file, as described below.
    """
    file = open(os.path.join('data', 'rates-'+date+'.csv'), 'wt')
    w = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
    w.writerow(['Code', 'Rate'])
    for key, value in sorted(rates.items()):
        w.writerow([key, value])
    file.close()
```

My program was working on Windows but when  I run it on Mac I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/rates-2001-03-03.csv'
```

How can I open the directory on Mac as well as Windows?

Comment: Does the `data/` directory exist on your Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you create the directory before creating a file inside that.

Comment: Thanks, at the beginning of code I've now written:

    if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')

And it works perfectly.